# I am working on fabric js and want to get id of current active object

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I am working on fabric js and i want to get the id of current selected (active) object.I have define the id of that object but at the time of modifying object i want to retrieve that id, but it is giving undefined.

I have tried this code

```
       <script>
       var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
                                            left: 100,
                                            top: 130,
                                            width: 622,
                                            height: 340,
                                            fill: 'white',
                                            stroke: '#ccc',
                                            //   sendToBack: true,
                                            lockRotation: true,
                                            bringToFront: true
                                        });

                                        // canvas.add(rect1);
                                        // create a rectangle object
                                        var t = new fabric.IText("622", {
                                            top: 140,
                                            left: 120,
                                            width: 50,
                                            height: 50,
                                            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                            fill: '#000000',
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            Scaling: false,
                                            hasRotatingPoint: false,
                                            transparentCorners: false,
                                            selectable: false,
                                            cornerSize: 7
                                        });

                                        var h = new fabric.IText("340", {
                                            top: 250,
                                            left: 110,
                                            width: 50,
                                            height: 50,
                                            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                            fill: '#000000',
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            Scaling: false,
                                            hasRotatingPoint: false,
                                            transparentCorners: false,
                                            selectable: true,
                                            selectionColor: 'blue',
                                            angle: 270,
                                            cornerSize: 7
                                        });

                                        var id = 'g1'
                                        var group1 = new      fabric.Group([rect1, t, h], {
                                           id: 'g1',
                                          name: 'g_one'
                                        });
                                        //console.log(group1);

                                        canvas.add(group1);


    canvas.on('object:modified', function (e) {
                                       var activeobject = e.target;


                               alert(activeobject.get('id'));

                                save_updated_obj();
                            });
   function save_updated_obj() {
                                var dat = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON());
                                //var d_id = groupobs.id; here i want to get id
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "json_append.php",
                                    data:  "value2=" + dat + "&id=" + 4,
                                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    //  dataType: "json",       
                                    success: function (v) {
                                        alert("OK");
                                          // alert(v);
                                           $('#json_data').val(v);
                                    },
                                });
                            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding attribute **myid** to group which is not **defined**. Set the attribute like this:

```js
var group1 = new fabric.Group([rect1, t, h], {
  id: 'g1',
  name: 'g_one'
});
```

[See Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub_rahman/q6a1ss9k/12/)

Comment: Thanks..I have tried the code you given but still giving undefined when i applied alert on modified function

Comment: thanks it is working but in my case it's not :( because after dropping multiple elements on canvas i have to find the id of selected element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set id in define array like this:

```js
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  id: 1,
  left: 100,
  top: 130,
  width: 622,
  height: 340,
  fill: 'white',
  stroke: '#ccc',
  //   sendToBack: true,
  lockRotation: true,
  bringToFront: true
});
```

and get modified object id with:

```js
fabric_canvas.on("object:modified", function() {
  var ao = fabric_canvas.getActiveObject();
  console.log('id:' + ao.id);
  console.log('top:' + ao.top); //get other property like this
  console.log('left:' + ao.left);
  console.log('scaleX:' + ao.scaleX);
  console.log('scaleY:' + ao.scaleY);
  console.log('rotateAngle:' + ao.angle);
})
```